# How to ensure that each part of $G$ differs at most one vertex in the proof of Turan theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-explanation, extremal-graph-theory

In [Diestel's *Graph Theory*](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ebilley/classes/562.winter.2018/articles/GraphTheory.pdf), I try to figure out the proof of Theorem 7.1.1 (Turan theorem) on page 165:

> For all integers $r, n$ with $r>1$, every $K_r$-free graph $G$ (i.e., $G$ does not have the $r-$complete graph $K_r$ as a subgraph) on $n$ vertices and $ex(n, K_r)$ (i.e., the maximum number of edges so that $G$ is $K_r$-free) is a $T^{r-1}(n)$. Here $T^{r-1}(n)$ is called Turan graph which is a unique $(r-1)-$multipartite graph with each parts differ at most one vertex.

I try to understand the first proof by induction and I am not sure if I understand it right.

Here we prove it by induction on $n$. Since $n\le r-1$ is a trivial case, $T^{r-1}(n)=K_{r-1}$ which is $K_r$-free as claimed.

For $n\ge r$, we assume that $G$ on the number of vertices $n$ is true (or say $n\le k$ is true), then we want to verify $n+1$ is also true (i.e., check $n=k+1$ holds).  Since $G$ is $K_{r}$-free, then it contains a subgraph $K_{r-1}$ (by the edge-maximal property).

Consider the graph $G-K_{r-1}$ that removes a subgraph $K_{r-1}$. Note that we count the number of edges of $G$ from three sources: the edges inside $K_{r-1}$, the edges between $K_{r-1}$ and $G-K_{r-1}$, and the edges inside $G-K_{r-1}$. So we upper bound the number of edges of $G$
$$
||G||\le \tbinom{r-1}{2}+(n-r+1)(r-2)+t_{r-1}(n-r+1)=t_{r-1}(n) --- (*)
$$
where the second term is because each vertex in $G-K_{r-1}$ has at most $r-2$ neighbors in $K_{r-1}$ (otherwise, there would be a $K_r$ subgraph in $G$), and the third term follows from the induction hypothesis since $n-r+1<n$. Since each part in $T^{r-1}(n)$ differs at most one vertex, we remove at most one vertex in each part for $G-K_{r-1}$. So the last equality holds.

Since $G$ is the extremal case on $n$ vertices, so the number of edges of $G$ is just equal to $t_{r-1}(n)$. Thus, the neighbors of each vertex of $G-K_{r-1}$ in $K_{r-1}$ is just $r-2$.

Then we need to show that such $G$ is just $T^{r-1}(n)$.

***[I am not very sure what the author means in the following proof]***

Consider $V(K_{r-1})=\{x_1,\dots, x_{r-1}\}$. Let
$$
V_i=\{v\in V(G): vx_i\notin E(G)\}, i=1,\dots, r-1
$$
be the set of all vertices of $G$ whose $r-2$ neighbors in $K_{r-1}$ are precisely the vertices other than $x_i$.

Note that each set $V_i$ is independent for all $i=1,\dots, r-1$ (because $G$ is $K_r$-free). Also, since $V_i$'s are independent and partition $V(G)$, then $G$ is $(r-1)$-partite. As $T^{r-1}(n)$ is the unique $(r-1)$-partite graph. Then we conclude that $G=T^{r-1}(n)$.

***Question***: How to ensure that each part of $G$ differs at most one vertex on the above construction? [Since the definition of $T^{r-1}(n)$ is the unique $(r-1)$-partite graph with each part differing at most 1 vertex].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point in the proof, we don't yet know the sizes of $V_1, \dots, V_{r-1}$; all we know is that they're independent sets and that they partition $V(G)$.

To prove more, we use the assumption that $G$ is a $K_r$-free graph with as many edges as possible. This tells us that:

1. $G$ must contain all the edges between different $V_i$'s, because adding those edges can't create a $K_r$. Therefore $G$ is a *complete* $(r-1)$-partite graph.
2. We can't have $|V_i| \ge |V_j| + 2$ for any $i,j$, because moving a vertex from $V_i$ to $V_j$ would increase the number of edges by $|V_i|-|V_j|-1 > 0$. Therefore $G$ is a nearly balanced complete $(r-1)$-partite graph.

The reason Diestel doesn't spell out point 2 is because the argument was already given right before the definition of $T_{r-1}(n)$.

---

Another possible argument would use the inductive hypothesis to argue that $G-K$ is isomorphic to $T_{r-1}(n-r+1)$. We can check that $V_1 - \{x_1\}, \dots, V_{r-1} - \{x_{r-1}\}$ are an $(r-1)$-partition of $G-K$, so it must be the case that the sizes $|V_1 - \{x_1\}|, \dots, |V_{r-1} - \{x_{r-1}\}|$ differ by at most $1$. Each of those sizes is one less than the corresponding size $|V_1|, \dots, |V_{r-1}|$, so these also differ by at most $1$.

---

As for the upper bound
$$
   \|G\| \le \binom{r-1}{2} + (n-r+1)(r-2) + t_{r-1}(n-r+1),
$$
it follows from counting the edges from three places: there are $\binom{r-1}{2}$ edges in $K$, at most $(n-r+1)(r-2)$ edges between $G-K$ and $K$ (since every one of the $n-r+1$ vertices outside $K$ has at most $r-2$ neighbors in $K$), and at most $t_{r-1}(n-r+1)$ edges outside $K$ (by induction, since $G-K$ is a $K_r$-free, $(n-r+1)$-vertex graph).

This upper bound is equal to $t_{r-1}(n)$, because if we take $T_{r-1}(n-r+1)$ and increase the size of each part by $1$, we both

- Add exactly $\binom{r-1}{2} + (n-r+1)(r-2)$ new edges, and
- Obtain exactly $T_{r-1}(n)$.

Comment: The second argument using inductive hypothesis is beautiful! But I am not very sure about why $V_1-\{x_1\}, V_1-\{x_2\},\dots, V_1-\{x_{r-1}\}$ are an $(r-1)$-partition of $G-K_{r-1}$? I mean why do we confirm that $G-K_{r-1}$ comes from removing one points from $V_1, \dots, V_{r-1}$ but the case removes two points from $V_1$, three points from $V_2$?

Comment: According to the definition of $V_i$, the only vertex of $K$ placed inside it is $x_i$.

Comment: (As a side note, you shouldn't say $G - K_{r-1}$ in this case; it's not precise. Diestel is very careful to distinguish $K_{r-1}$ (a generic $(r-1)$-clique) from $K$ (the set of $r-1$ vertices we chose that make up a copy of $K_{r-1}$ inside $G$.))

Comment: Sorry, I am confused about your side note. Dose $G-K_{r-1}$ mean the graph $G$ removing a subgraph $(r-1)$-complete graph? I am not sure your $K_{r-1}$? You mean $K^{r-1}$ and $K_{r-1}$ are two different notations?

Comment: Diestel uses $K^{r-1}$ where most people use $K_{r-1}$, but I am ignoring that. What I'm pointing out is that Diestel defines $K$ to be the set $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{r-1}\}$ we picked out at the beginning of the proof; $G-K$ is the subgraph obtained by deleting those vertices. It is unclear what $G - K_{r-1}$ would mean.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. But at the beginning of the proof in Diestel's textbook, he did not say $K=\{x_1,\dots, x_{r-1}\}$ when he considered $G-K$. So that is not clear, right?

Comment: Also, can I ask why (*) in my question holds for that equality?

Comment: I've added some detail on (*) in my answer. It's true that Diestel does not define $x_1, \dots, x_{r-1}$ until later.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask why the number of edges of $G$ is just $t_{r-1}(n)$? The textbook says that is because $G$ is extremal for $K^r$ and $T^{r-1}(n)$ does not have subgraph $K^r$. So why do we have $\|G\|=t_{r-1}(n)$ from the last sentence?

Comment: We know that $\|G\| \ge t_{r-1}(n)$ because $G$ has the largest number of edges in a $K_r$-free graph, so it should have at least as many as $T_{r-1}(n)$ does. We know that $\|G\| \le t_{r-1}(n)$ from this inequality.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think my induction assumption is correct? 'For $n\ge r$, we assume that $G$ on the number of vertices $n$ is true (or say $n\le k$ is true), then we want to verify $n+1$ is also true (i.e., check $n=k+1$ holds).  Since $G$ is $K_{r}$-free, then it contains a subgraph $K_{r-1}$ (by the edge-maximal property). ’

Comment: What does it mean for $G$ to be "true"? To prove that $T_{r-1}(n)$ is the unique $n$-vertex $K_r$-free graph with the most edges, we assume that $T_{r-1}(n-r)$ is the unique $(n-r)$-vertex $K_r$-free graph with the most edges: we use the $n-r$ case to prove the $n$ case. You can phrase this as a strong induction if you like.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. Our statement is that the $K_r$-free graph $G$ on n vertices with $ex(n, K_r)$ is just $T_{r-1}(n)$. For $n\ge r-1$, this is a trivial case. We just need to consider $n\ge r$. Here our induction hypothesis is that ' $K_r$-free graph $G$ on $(n-1)$ vertices (or less than $(n-1)$) with $ex(n-1, K_r)$ is just $T_{r-1}(n-1)$'. We want to check that for n is also true. Does my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the strong induction version.